# Gorilla/Martini sessions not working in Cloud9 IDE environment

Tags: go, cloud9-ide, martini, gorilla

I've been experimenting with Go web application development in the [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) environment.  So far I've had no success with using [Gorilla](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/) sessions (which are also the underlying mechanism for sessions in the [Martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini) web framework).  However, the exact same code DOES work successfully in any other environment.

To reproduce the issue, you can cut-n-paste the exact "Hello World" style example app from the Martini sessions add-on (see [here](https://github.com/martini-contrib/sessions)).  In this simple example, the "/set" URL places a value on the session, and the "/get" URL displays the value that was previously set.

In a Cloud9 IDE project, calling the "/get" URL logs the following to the console:

```
[martini] [sessions] ERROR! illegal base64 data at input byte 155
```

I get similar results when trying to test Gorilla directly.  However, when running any of this exact same source code, unmodified, in my local environment (or in a Nitrous.IO cloud environment), it works just fine.

Is anyone doing Go web development on Cloud9, and have any insights into this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that our (Cloud9) application proxy does not encode all cookies properly. We have a fix for that, which should go live very soon.